# Title: Issue with Writing Characteristic in BLE Android App for Inverter Monitoring

Tags: esp32, android-bluetooth

Title: Issue with Writing Characteristics in BLE Android App for Inverter Monitoring

Description:

I am developing an Android app to monitor my inverter using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). The app successfully connects to the inverter device, and I am able to read characteristics without any problems. However, I am facing issues with the "write characteristic" functionality.
package com. eapro.myproject;
import static androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.TAG;

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.clj.fastble.BleManager;
import com.clj.fastble.callback.BleIndicateCallback;
import com.clj.fastble.callback.BleMtuChangedCallback;
import com.clj.fastble.callback.BleWriteCallback;
import com.clj.fastble.data.BleDevice;
import com.clj.fastble.exception.BleException;
import com.clj.fastble.utils.HexUtil;

import com.eapro.myproject.comm.Observer;
import com.eapro.myproject.comm.ObserverManager;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView;


public class MainScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable, Observer {
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    public static final String Tag="DetailBle";
    boolean MAINSSTATUS;
    boolean SOLARSTATUS;
    boolean UPSSTATUS;
    boolean BATTERYFULL;
    String  CHARGING_STATUS,CHARGING_LABEL;
    View view;
    LinearLayout statusLayout;
    int psckecked;
    Alarms alarms;

    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristicsList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<BluetoothGattService> servicesList;
    BleDevice bleDevice;
    BluetoothGattService service;
    List<StringBuilder> builderList;

    // here we define our variable connected to xml file

    LinearLayout solarArrowLoad, solarArrowBattery, gridArrowLoad, gridArrowBattery,batteryArrowLoad;


    TextView solarToloadP,solarToBatteryCur;
            //gridToLoadP,gridToBatteryCu;  ye comment kiye hai
//    todayPS  totalps,solarPower  ye bhi comment kiya hai

    TextView solarCurrent,batteryVolt,batteryCurrent,SRnumber, gridVolt,loadPersent;
    TextView connetionStatus;
    Button upsStatus,upsMode,highCharging,powerSaving;  // btn to txt here error
    ImageView solarPanel,battery,homeLoad,supply;
    //


    //

    int writeFlag;

    ClickDialog clickDialog;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_ble);
        ObserverManager.Companion.getInstance().addObserver(this);
        mBluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        BleDevice bleDevice1 = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bleDevice"); //BLE class object
//      bleDevice1.getName().toString();


        if (bleDevice1 != null){
            Log.d("","javed"+bleDevice1.getName());
            start(bleDevice1);
        }

        // D4:D4:DA:30:8D:62
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "yaha dikaat hai ky  bhai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    void start(BleDevice bleDevice1){
        bleDevice=bleDevice1;
        Log.d("","oldhai"+bleDevice.getName());


        if (bleDevice!=null){


            if (BleManager.getInstance().isConnected(bleDevice)){
                initView();
                setData();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                //notifyClick();
               write("hello sir"); //1
                Log.d("Tag","msg"+write("i am coder"));
                Log.d("Tag","msg"+write("i am coder"));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                indicate();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }

                setMTU();


            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Device is not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(Tag+"onCreate","Device id not connected");
        }
        setConnectivityStatus();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        //start handler as activity become visible
        // startCkeckStatus();
        super.onResume();
    }


    private void setConnectivityStatus() {
        if (getConnectivityStatus()) {
            connetionStatus.setText(getText(R.string.connected));
            Log.d(Tag,"Connected");
        }
        else {
            connetionStatus.setText(R.string.active_disconnected);
            Log.d(Tag,"Disconnected");
        }

    }

    private boolean getConnectivityStatus() {
        return  BleManager.getInstance().isConnected(bleDevice);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (bleDevice!=null){
            BleManager.getInstance().disconnect(bleDevice);
            BleManager.getInstance().destroy();}
        stopNotification();
    }

    private void initView() {
        servicesList = new ArrayList<>();
        builderList= new ArrayList<>();

        connetionStatus=findViewById(R.id.connected_status);

        solarToloadP=findViewById(R.id.solar_to_load_power);
        solarToBatteryCur=findViewById(R.id.solar_to_battery_current);
        // 208 and 209 and 214 ,2013.1113,1117,1118,1198,1120 these line will be connected
    //    gridToLoadP=findViewById(R.id.grid_to_load_power);
    //    gridToBatteryCu=findViewById(R.id.grid_to_battery_current);

//        todayPS=findViewById(R.id.today_power_saved);
//        totalPS=findViewById(R.id.total_power_saved);

  //      solarPower=findViewById(R.id.solar_power);
        //  solarCurrent=findViewById(R.id.solar_current);
        SRnumber = findViewById(R.id.serialNO);
        gridVolt =findViewById(R.id.ip_volt);
        loadPersent=findViewById(R.id.load_presentge);
        batteryVolt=findViewById(R.id.battery_volt);
        batteryCurrent=findViewById(R.id.battrery_to_load_power);



        upsStatus=findViewById(R.id.ups_status);
       upsMode=findViewById(R.id.ups_mode);
        highCharging=findViewById(R.id.high_charging);
        powerSaving=findViewById(R.id.power_saving);

        solarPanel=findViewById(R.id.solar_panel);
        supply=findViewById(R.id.supply);
        battery=findViewById(R.id.battery);
        homeLoad=findViewById(R.id.load);

        gridArrowLoad =findViewById(R.id.grid_arroweup);
        gridArrowBattery =findViewById(R.id.grid_arrowdown);

        solarArrowLoad =findViewById(R.id.solar_arrow_up);
        solarArrowBattery =findViewById(R.id.solar_arrow_mid);
        batteryArrowLoad =findViewById(R.id.battery_to_load);

    }

    private void setData() {
        BluetoothGatt gatt = BleManager.getInstance().getBluetoothGatt(bleDevice);
        alarms=new Alarms(MainScreen.this);

        clickDialog = new ClickDialog(MainScreen.this);
        view =getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        for (BluetoothGattService service : gatt.getServices()) {
            servicesList.add(service);

        }
        service = servicesList.get(2); // 3-1 services chl rhe hai
    //    Log.d("","i am ser"+service);
////        Log.d("","service1"+service.getCharacteristics().get(1));
//        Log.d("","service1"+servicesList.get(1));
//        Log.d("","service0"+servicesList.get(0));
//        Log.d("","service2"+servicesList.get(2));
        characteristicsList.addAll(service.getCharacteristics());

        /* ************************************* Button ******************************************* */
//        upsStatus.setOnClickListener(view -> {
//            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "data is coming",
//                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            if (!builderList.isEmpty()) {
//                if (upsStatus.getText() == getString(R.string.ups_on)) {
//                    Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "data is coming",
//                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    // String input = builderList.get(1).toString() + "%" + getString(R.string.ups_off) + "%" + "END";
//                    String input = builderList.get(7).toString() + "%" + "OFF"+ "%" + "END";
//                    Log.d("","buton"+ input);
//                    int status = write(input);
//                    if (status == 4)
//                        upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_off));
//
//                    else
//                        Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
//                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//                } else {
//                    //  String input = builderList.get(1).toString() + "%" + getString(R.string.ups_on) + "%" + "END";
//                    String input = builderList.get(7).toString() + "%" + " ON"+ "%" + "END";
//                    int status = write(input);
//                    Log.d("YourTag", "write method executed. Status: " + status);
//                    if (status == 1)
//                        upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_on));
//                    else
//                        Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
//                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }
//            }
//
//        });

        // button hai yha p

        upsStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (!builderList.isEmpty()) {
                    if (upsStatus.getText() == getString(R.string.ups_on)) {

                        // String input = mArrayList.get(1).toString() + "%" + getString(R.string.ups_off) + "%" + "END";
                        String input = builderList.get(1).toString() + "%" + "OFF" + "%" + "END";
                        Log.d("","upsss"+builderList.get(13).toString());
                        int status = write(input);
                        if (status == 1)
                            upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_off));
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        //  String input = mArrayList.get(1).toString() + "%" + getString(R.string.ups_on) + "%" + "END";
                        String input = builderList.get(1).toString() + "%" + " ON" + "%" + "END";
                        int status = write(input);
                        if (status == 1)
                            upsStatus.setText(getString(R.string.ups_on));
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "Operation Fail try again",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Sharing the code and where the exception came from will help other understand what is going on here.

Comment: when i write on of from android app to ble esp32

Comment: please review my code

Comment: please review my code

Comment: here is my code please help me its my first project .

Comment: @tomerpacific please help me hereis my code.